# Function not triggering on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to trigger a certain function in a collection view when I scroll. Basically Im trying to implement pagination so that when it scrolls to the bottom more items are loaded.

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.item >= allEvents.count - 1 {
            // print("paginating for post")
            paginationHelper.paginate(completion: { [unowned self] (events) in
                self.allEvents.append(contentsOf: events)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }else{
            print("Not paginating")
        }
    }
```

This is the entire Function

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator
import SwiftLocation
import CoreLocation
import AMScrollingNavbar

class HomeFeedController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    // let dropDownLauncher = DropDownLauncher()
    var isFinishedPaging = false
    let detailView = EventDetailViewController()
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    var emptyLabel: UILabel?
    var allEvents = [Event]()
    //will containt array of event keys
    var eventKeys = [String]()
    let customCellIdentifier = "customCellIdentifier"
    var grideLayout = GridLayout(numberOfColumns: 2)
    lazy var dropDownLauncer : DropDownLauncher = {
        let launcer = DropDownLauncher()
        launcer.homeFeed = self
        return launcer
    }()
    let paginationHelper = PaginationHelper<Event>(serviceMethod: PostService.showEvent)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = grideLayout
        collectionView?.reloadData()
        self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 0, 0)
        navigationItem.title = "Home"
        collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier)
        //  self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDropDownMenu))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

        //        PostService.showEvent(location: User.current.location!) { (event) in
        //            self.allEvents = event
        //            print(self.allEvents)
        //
        //            DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        //            }
        //        }
        configureCollectionView()
        reloadHomeFeed()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let navigationController = self.navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
            navigationController.followScrollView(self.collectionView!, delay: 50.0)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        if let navigationController = navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
            navigationController.stopFollowingScrollView()
        }
    }

    override func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
        if let navigationController = navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
            navigationController.showNavbar(animated: true)
        }
        return true
    }



    func handleDropDownMenu(){
        dropDownLauncer.showDropDown()
    }
    //will query by selected category
    func categoryFetch(dropDown: DropDown){
        navigationItem.title = dropDown.name
        paginationHelper.category = dropDown.name
        configureCollectionView()
        reloadHomeFeed()
    }

    func reloadHomeFeed() {
        self.paginationHelper.reloadData(completion: { [unowned self] (events) in
            self.allEvents = events

            if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }


    func configureCollectionView() {
        // add pull to refresh
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadHomeFeed), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView?.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }

    // need to tell it how many cells to have

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allEvents.count
    }

    // need to tell the collection view controller what type of cell we want to return
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let imageURL = URL(string: allEvents[indexPath.item].currentEventImage)
        print(imageURL ?? "")
        customCell.sampleImage.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL!)
        return customCell
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //let selectedEvent = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
        //let eventDetailVC
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath){
            //  print("Look here for event name")
            // print(detailView.eventName)
            detailView.eventKey = allEvents[indexPath.row].key!
            detailView.eventPromo = allEvents[indexPath.row].currentEventPromo!
            detailView.currentEvent = allEvents[indexPath.row]
            present(detailView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)

        }
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.item >= allEvents.count - 1 {
            // print("paginating for post")
            paginationHelper.paginate(completion: { [unowned self] (events) in
                self.allEvents.append(contentsOf: events)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }else{
            print("Not paginating")
        }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //will make surepictures keep same orientation even if you flip screen
    // will most likely lock into portrait mode but still good to have
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        grideLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
    //Will allow the first two cells that are displayed to be of varying widths
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.item == 0 || indexPath.item == 1 {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: grideLayout.itemSize.height)
        }else{
            return grideLayout.itemSize
        }
    }
    func showLeftView(sender: AnyObject?){
        print("Button Pressed")
        // sideMenuController?.leftViewController = LeftViewController()
        //sideMenuController?.showLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }

}
//responsible for populating each cell with content

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    let sampleImage: UIImageView = {
        let firstImage = UIImageView()
        firstImage.clipsToBounds = true
        firstImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        firstImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return firstImage
    }()
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let name = UILabel()
        name.text = "Custom Text"
        name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return name
    }()
    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(sampleImage)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        //addSubview(nameLabel)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": sampleImage]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": sampleImage]))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
// responsible for creating the grid layout that you see in the home view feed

class GridLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var numberOfColumns:Int = 2

    init(numberOfColumns: Int) {
        super.init()
        // controlls spacing inbetween them as well as spacing below them to next item
        self.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    }
    // just needs to be here because swift tells us to
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override var itemSize: CGSize{
        get{
            if collectionView != nil {
                let collectionVieweWidth = collectionView?.frame.width
                let itemWidth = (collectionVieweWidth!/CGFloat(self.numberOfColumns)) - self.minimumInteritemSpacing
                let itemHeight: CGFloat = 200
                return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
            }
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }set{
            super.itemSize = newValue
        }
    }


}
```

This is the function that is responsible for triggering the event but it seems to go to the else statement literally every time. Any insight would be helpful

Comment: add your number of items and section datasource methods in question

Comment: you called two blocks here , so you need to wait for delay

Comment: If every time ` print("Not paginating")` executes then problem is in this statement: `indexPath.item >= allEvents.count - 1` , recheck do you need this condition or som other?

Comment: see edits please and what do you mean by two blocks and I'm not sure that's what the tutorial said to use and it worked for them.@3stud1ant3

Comment: see edits please @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Try `indexPath.row == allEvents.count - 1` and see if it works.

Comment: @Amit that did not work

Comment: AllEvents.count is 4

Comment: indexpath.row is 4

Comment: You claim it doesn't go into the `if` part, only the `else` part. How do you know? Are you just guessing??? You have a wonderful debugger. Debug! Put a breakpoint and step through the code. See where it goes. See what the variables are. Solve your own problem!

Comment: seemingly did not load anything upon that change

Comment: I know it goes in the else because I put a breakpoint there @matt and it repeatedly goes there. I'm definitely not just guessing

Comment: Do you see `Not paginating` in the console everytime?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 yes I do

Comment: @matt I tried. I always try to solve my problem before I come here for help. If you do not have anything constructive to say don't say it all, please.

Comment: you are saying AllEvents.count is 4 and indexpath.row is 4 , so with this , `indexPath.item >= allEvents.count - 1` will always be `false`, I think you need to recheck this condition

Comment: im sorry indexPath.row was 2 when I checked it

Comment: allEvents.count -1 was 3 @3stud1ant3

Comment: Uncomment the print statement of `print("paginating for post")` , see if it is printing?if what you are saying about the allEvents.count and indexPath.item is true, then it should print

Comment: Yes it does occosianaly but there are a couple not paginating for post calls thrown in there

Comment: If you comment `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` then what is the behaviour?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 on white line I have that there a couple times

Comment: @3stud1ant3 oh I see it nevermind

Comment: @3stud1ant3 still nothing can i send you my github link so you can see the actual project